# I need a better solution for invalidating previous user avatar's in my app (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am doing the following to store and invalidate an avatar when a user changes it:

- Avatars are stored by userid, split automatically into folders of 1000 each (in order to help the filesystem and avoid having millions of files in each directory)
- my function for retrieving a users avatar takes their
  userid/sex/version number - if version number is more than 0 then a
  param `?ver=$ver` is appened to the URL so that any cached avatars
  get redownloaded by other users.
- If the version number is 0 then the url returns a default avatar based on their 'sex'
- The sex and avatar version is stored in my userdata table and the version is incremented every time the user changes his/her avatar.

This works well and is minimizing database lookups since at any given point I already will have the userdata required to generate a relevant and current avatar based on userid/sex/version.  There is no need to query again or perform any joins to get a user's current avatar.

However, now that I am adding an activity feed I am running into problems.

Given the nature of activity feeds we are generally storing story data as JSON (fanning-out with Redis and using MySQL as a persistence layer etc.. etc...)

Within any given activity we have been storing the userid,sex,version number of the user to avoid having to perform a JOIN when retrieving the information.  Of course this means that if a users avatar gets changed then any old activities may be displaying the old avatar.

I am looking for a way around this problem that ideally doesn't involve adding JOIN's when querying our activity feed.

So far the only solution I can come up with is to append a param based on time() when querying the activity feed ensuring that any new avatars are downloaded.  But of course this means that for the feed, no avatars are ever cached in the users browser.

The other option is to queue updates to the feeds and go through and amend every single relevant feed with the new avatar version, but this seems ridiculous.

The only other thought I have had was to get all friends avatar version numbers upon login and store them in a large array somewhere during the session then simply append those to the various avatar URL's instead.  meaning there is one lookup rather than many.  But then of course.... This doesn't deal with comments on activities from users who you are not friends with/following.  But then again, do up to date avatars really matter for people you are not following?  Perhaps not.

Every solution seems to have its share of faults to me.

Are there any other options available to me?  Should I go back to the drawing board with regards to avatar url storage (though I really cant see another way of historically storing these URL's and having them update automatically within a feed).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: is the actual avatar also stored in the db?

Comment: No, and that is by design.  The url is generated in a function on demand taking into account the users 'userid/sex/avatar_ver'

Comment: Sorry, I missread that. Why don't you let the webserver figure it out. Set a must-revalidate directive on the avatar folders/files. Then if a file is changed, your server will serve the new version.

Comment: Now thats actually a great idea... Although I'm not totally sure how I would go about implementing it. We are serving files with apache and nginx used as a static proxy. If you could elaborate this into an answer that would be great.  I think you might have hit the nail on the head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm not quite sure about your configuration but I would think in nginx this would do it:

```
location ^~ /avatars/ {
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

And in apache:

```
Header set Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate"
```

Comment: Yes that looks about right. Although it's more about how to set this on demand for a specific file in PHP and then to reset it after the first access.  That's what i'm mostly unsure about, if it's even at all possible.  This is a fantastic solution though, if I can get it to work.  For that reason I'm going to leave the question open for a few more hours just in case someone comes by with a complete solution, if not i'll answer your as correct..  Thanks!

Comment: I've actually just realized that this won't quite work event if I can work out how to change the headers within my app on demans.  As how would I know when to reset the cache headers?  There would be no way of knowing I suppose.  It wouldn't be too dissimilar from appending a time() param to the end of the url.  That said, perhaps combining a shorter expiry on avatars with the $GLOBAL array of avatar versions might do the trick.

Comment: You won't set it on demand but you set this for a whole folder or set of files. Once the user changes his avatar the avatar on the disk changes (duh). Every client will send a request to the webserver and will ask if the file was changed. If so, the webserver will tell the client and it can fetch a new version. If now, the client will get it from it's cache

Comment: Oh i see! so these headers would automatically tell if the file had changed?  Forgive me my server knowledge is minimal.

Comment: yes, browser asks if the file has changed and webserver will tell if it has changed or not.

Comment: It works perfectly!  Many thanks for all your help Nin.  I really should get around to learner more server stuff. :)